# Azure - Availability set Change Domain Values

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-availability-set

I explicitly created an **Availability Set** via the **Azure console**. I can launch VM's in successfully by selecting the Availability Set.

When I review the **Availability Set** in the console, I do not have an option to edit the **Fault Domain** or **Update Domains** values.

Are there options to perform this Action?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Yes, you can use [REST api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/availabilitysets/createorupdate), or resources.azure.com to edit those values. Powershell\Cli have commands to edit those (`Update-AzAvailabilitySet`).</strike>

It appears these values are read only after creating the resource

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in that direction, it looks promising, however.  I tried using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/update-azavailabilityset?view=azps-2.6.0#examples. But could not construct a command that would change this value.

This is far as I reached 

Get-AzAvailabilitySet -ResourceGroupName 'mygroup' -Name 'nameofset' | Update-AzAvailabilitySet -Sku 'Aligned' 

I don't know how to specify the values to change...

Comment: interesting, it appears changing these values is blocked in the rest api, so I'm afraid you cannot do that.